# How to undo bypassSecurityTrustHtml, i.e convert SafeValue back to string

Tags: angular, html-sanitizing

I am generating html, and inserting it into my web page using

```
let data = '<font color=blue>hello world</font>';
this.safevalue = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data);
```

Elsewhere in my code I want to convert the safe value back into a string, so I tried this...

```
data = this.safevalue.toString();
```

but this sets data to a string like this...

```
'SafeValue must use [property]=binding: (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)'
```

which is not helpful

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(this.safevalue)`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I get the same thing as toString.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know if you already found a fix for this, but, if you just want the original value, marked as safe:

```
var yourString = this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, data)
```

Comment: Does this work? If the data is "Hello world" then will the value of `yourString.toString()` be also "Hello world"?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's how I am doing in my application here. Give it a try and let me know if you need any help!
You just have to use yourString (no need for .toString(), it is a slready a string)

Answer (score 0):

I've dug through the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.6/packages/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.ts#L18-L26) and it appears that it is ***not possible*** to get the original string from a `SafeValue`.  So I guess I'll have to keep parallel data array for all the unsafe values.