# Access internal value of Angular SafeValue

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `SafeValue` and need to access the internally wrapped value. Currently I do it like this:

```
const mySafeValue = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('42px solid black');
console.log(mySafeValue['changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity']);
```

This works great but I'm pretty sure this is not how you should do it. What is the recommended way to get back a value that is wrapped as a `SafeValue`?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959219/how-to-undo-bypasssecuritytrusthtml-i-e-convert-safevalue-back-to-string) can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked answer by Powkachu was providing the correct answer. You can get the value by using the sanitizer.

`const myValue = this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, mySafeValue)`

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, this might also work:

```
import { ɵunwrapSafeValue as unwrapSafeValue } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeValue } from '@angular/platform-browser';
const myValue = unwrapSafeValue(mySafeValue as SafeValue);
```

Note the [ɵ character](https://unicode-table.com/en/0275/), which denotes a private Angular API afaik. The `as SafeValue` seems necessary when `mySafeValue` is declared as a sub-type, e.g. `SafeHtml`.

Imho this isn't much better than the original approach from the question. And certainly much worse than [felix-engelmann](/users/4518105/felix-engelmann)'s own answer. Just wanted to put it out there.